# Put data into textboxes when item is selected in combobox

Tags: javascript, php, html, combobox

I have a combobox with a name and ID of "device". When a device is selected from the combobox e.g. "iPhone 1st Gen", I want a text field with a name and ID of "processor" to fill with the processor name e.g. "Underclocked 412Mhz".

How can I do this?

I can use HTML, PHP and Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Ajax. The most easy way is making the AJAX request with jQuery. 
Below an example:

Call a JavaScript function when the 'change' event ocurred on your combobox:

```
<select id="device" onchange="changeDevice(this.id);">[your options]</select>
```

Make an ajax request in your JavaScript method:

```
function changeDevice(deviceID){    
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'[url of your php file]',
    dataType:'text',
    data:{device_id:deviceID},
    success:function(response){
        //assign the text response to your input text
        $('#processor').val(response);
    }
});}
```

Comment: Would you be able to fill in the placeholders with some examples for me please?

Comment: jQuery can also help with that: $('#[id_of_your_input]').attr('placeholder','[your text for attribute]');

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this with plain old Javascript

```
<select name="combo">
<option value="dog">Dog</option>
<option value="cat">Cat</option>
<option value="Duck">Duck</option>
<option value="Rabbit">Rabbit</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="picked" id="picked">
<script>
document.getElementsByName('combo').item(0).onchange = function(){
     document.getElementsByName('picked').item(0).value = document.getElementsByName('combo').item(0).value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Would this work if the value I want to appear in the text box is different from the combobox value?

Comment: You can certainly change the values  ie `<option value="kennel">Dog</option>` because the user won't see the values declared.

Comment: But if I need to fill several fields, how do I do that?

Comment: I'd prefer to use this option as I can kind of understand how to edit it, so is there a way to fill say 10 text boxes on combobox change?